# Using MSBuild's CL task doesn't create executable

Tags: c, visual-c++, msbuild, compilation

I'm trying to build a "Hello World" C program using MSBuild's CL task as follows:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask TaskName="CL" AssemblyFile="%ASSEMBLYDLL%" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="main.c" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <CL Sources="@(Compile)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

**This creates a `main.obj`** by calling `cl.exe /c main.c`, but **I want to create a `main.exe`**. If I call `cl.exe main.c` on the command-line it works of course. However **I want to know how to control this through MSBuild**. I could not find information on this [at the corresponding reference page at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee862477.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've overlooked that calling `cl.exe main.c` actually calls `cl.exe main.c && link.exe main.obj`, creating a `main.exe`. The following works as expected.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask TaskName="CL" AssemblyFile="%ASSEMBLYDLL%" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="Link" AssemblyFile="%ASSEMBLYDLL%" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="main.c" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <CL Sources="@(Compile)" />
    <Link Sources="@(Compile -> '%(Filename).obj')" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```